# ssh_config equivalent to ssh -t

Tags: ssh, configuration, tty

Is there an equivalent to [`ssh -t`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) in the ssh config?

[image: man page ssh -t]

I couldn't find anything in the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

`OpenSSH` >= `8.9`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#RequestTTY

> **RequestTTY**
>
> Specifies whether to request a pseudo-tty for the session. The argument may be one of: no (never request a TTY), yes (always request
> a TTY when standard input is a TTY), force (always request a TTY) or
> auto (request a TTY when opening a login session). This option mirrors
> the -t and -T flags for ssh(1).

You have been looking at a very old manual, e.g. it even mentions SSH *protocol version 1* support, which has been finally *deleted* from OpenSSH back in 2017. Per Release notes, the `RequestTTY` option was added [in OpenSSH 5.9/5.9p1 (2011-09-06)](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html#5.9).